# How to create pagination of file in directory?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, pagination

i have listed all specific files (*.htm) from one directory using this code :

```
  <?PHP
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator('..\articles/');
foreach($iterator as $fileInfo){
    if($fileInfo->isFile()){
        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getCTime());
        echo "<div id='NewsWrap'>"
        . "<div id='NewsTitle'>"
        . "<a href='http://localhost/test/articles/" . basename($fileInfo->getFileName()) . "'>" . basename($fileInfo->getFileName(), '.htm') . "</a></div>"
        . "<div id='NewsCreation'>" . "on " .  $cTime->format('d-m-Y') . " by : Admin</div>"
        . "</div>";

    }
}
?>
```

because so many files are displayed, then I want to make pagination (10 files each pa).. but I do not have any idea to do that with my code..

And I do not want to use jquery, but if necessary..so be it.

**EDIT : Another Method**

```
<?PHP
    $offset = 2;
    $quantity = 5;
    $filelist = scandir('../articles/', 0);

    $selectedFiles = array_slice($filelist, $offset, $quantity);

    foreach($selectedFiles as $SplFileInfo)
    {
        if (!is_dir("../articles/". $SplFileInfo))
        {
            echo "<div id='NewsWrap'>"
            . "<div id='NewsTitle'>"
            . "<a href='http://localhost/test/articles/" . basename($SplFileInfo) . "' target='IFContent'>" . basename($SplFileInfo, '.htm') . "</a></div>"
            . "<div id='NewsCreation'>on " . date ("d F Y", filemtime("../articles/". $SplFileInfo)) . " by : Admin</div>"
            . "<div id='NewsDemo'>" . file_get_contents('../articles/'. $SplFileInfo) . "')</div>"
            . "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

but still i have no luck to create pagination number..
can someone to modify a litle my code to add pagination number..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason not to use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) instead of `Filesystemiterator()`. `Scandir()` will return an array of files (and directories) within the specified path. You may also use `sorting order` to sort them however you wish.

```
var files = scandir('..\articles/');
var page = 1;  //change when new page is requested
var FILES_PER_PAGE = 10;


for (i = page * FILES_PER_PAGE; i < page * FILES_PER_PAGE + FILES_PER_PAGE; i++) {
    //display HTML
}
```

You'll notice `page * FILES_PER_PAGE` creates the lower bound for pages to be displayed and `page * FILES_PER_PAGE + FILES_PER_PAGE` creates the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `jQuery` then the only way to show your files in pagination is you need to show/hide your file names for example,

1. You need to count the total files found in a folder.
2. Then you need to get the page numbers by using your files per page number, for example you have 52 number of files and you want to show 10 files per page then your total number of pages are 6 `((int)52/10+((52%10)>0?1:0))` for extra 2 files we need to get an extra page that why I used `((52%10)>0?1:0)`.
3. No, what you need to create pagination links(From second point you need to create 6 links).
4. By default starting 10(number of page showing) are shown and rest of file names are hidden.
5. No when clicking on page number you need to show the files for that number and rest of file names are hidden. For example, if you click on 3 then you will show 29 to 39 indexed(as starting from 0) files and rest files are hidden.

But if you use jQuery then it would be easy to implement it without any major complexity. Try the snippet to show/hide the files.

```js
$('.pagination li').on('click',function(){
  p=$(this).data('page'),
  $list=$('.list');
  $list.find('li[data-filePage!="'+p+'"]').hide();
  $list.find('li[data-filePage="'+p+'"]').show();
});
```

```css
.list{list-style:none}
.list li{display:none;}

.pagination{list-style:none;}
.pagination li {float:left;padding:0 5px;border:1px solid #444;cursor:pointer;margin:0 2px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li data-filePage="1" style="display:block">1</li>
  <li data-filePage="1" style="display:block">2</li>
  <li data-filePage="2">3</li>
  <li data-filePage="2">4</li>
  <li data-filePage="3">5</li>
  <li data-filePage="3">6</li>
  <li data-filePage="4">7</li>
</ul>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li data-page="1">1</li>
  <li data-page="2">2</li>
  <li data-page="3">3</li>
  <li data-page="4">4</li>
  </ul>
```

You can use a simple [ajax pagination](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php), only you need to change the php code.